# Проблема с функцией date php

Tags: дата, php, время

Проблема следующая я сохраняю дату в числовом виде (в секундах, результат функции `mktime(0,0,0,$ndate[1],$ndate[0],$ndate[2]);`). Вывожу с помощью `date('d.m.Y', $time_from_base);` На одном сервере у меня отображается 19 мая допустим, а на другом 20 мая. Т.е. везде разница 1 день. Разница во времени у серверов 1 час, но я так понимаю это вообще никак влиять не должно.

Answer (score 1):

[[@oldy](/users/17689/oldy)](/users/17689/oldy) Попробуйте выставит на каждом сервере: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: Это понятно, что нужно одну зону выставить. Но как быть с уже введенными данными? Я всегда думал, что date просто форматирует дату, которую высчитывает, как 1970 + $time_from_base, разве это не так?

Comment: @oldy Зависит от заданного формата. К примеру, `date('U')` есть не что иное, как `time()`. В иных же случаях, `date('d.m.Y')` вернёт дату в соответствии с таймзоной

Comment: > Но как быть с уже введенными данными?

В СУБД? Если да, то какой тип данных используете `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME`?

Comment: просто int

Comment: @oldy Если у Вас одна БД и несколько серверов с бизнес-логикой, которые заносят в БД дату с разной таймзоной, то без изменение данных в БД не обойтись, либо в БД должны храниться данные с идентификатором сервера.

Небольшое замечание. `int` и `TIMESTAMP` по 4 байта. Использование типа `TIMESTAMP` даёт ряд преимуществ,  к примеру, можно использовать операции БД по работе с датами. Тип `int` может пригодится при миграции с разных СУБД.

Почитайте этот [пост](http://habrahabr.ru/post/61391/)